# Five-letter words with unique letters containing G and P

Tags: word

Find the five-letter words with no repeating letters, that also contain both the letters `G` and `P`.

Comment: Hello @Sonja Thomason. There are many word sites on the net that can give you all kinds of words. The Free Dictionary site for example can allow you commands like Words: Starting with, Ending with, Containing etc. You will find dozens satisfying what you are looking for

Comment: I answered, but +1 @DEEM - I have to admit I don't see the purpose of the "puzzle"

Answer (score 1):

With no letters more than once:

aping 
galop 
gamps 
gaped 
gaper 
gapes 
gawps 
genip 
getup 
gimps 
gimpy 
gipon 
gipsy 
glops 
glyph 
gorps 
gramp 
grape 
graph 
grapy 
grasp 
gripe 
grips 
gript 
gripy 
grope 
group 
grump 
gulps 
gulpy 
oping 
paged 
pager 
pages 
pagod 
pangs 
parge 
pargo 
peage 
peags 
pengo 
phage 
pigmy 
pingo 
pings 
pirog 
plage 
plugs 
podgy 
pogey 
pongs 
porgy 
prang 
prigs 
progs 
prong 
pudge 
pudgy 
pungs 
purge 
spang 
sprag 
sprig 
sprug 
unpeg

If non-concurrent letters can repeat (not sure on repeat definition):

agape 
gasps 
gypsy 
pagan 
panga 
pygmy 
repeg

Comment: The letter a appears twice in agape.

Comment: Good call... somehow overlooked the first word I had

Answer (score 0):

There are several words fufilling this property.

> `GIMPY`, `GROUP`, `GRUMP`, `PURGE`.

Why do you ask?